# Linear interpolation or resampling in R

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation, sampling

I have a question related to interpolation. I have 2 columns ($1 is time in seconds, the other sea level). The examples I have tried mostly come from columns as date e.g. 1970-11-11, but I have records as seconds that I want to linearly interpolate to minutes. Sampling is originally every 0.3 second. Any suggestions please about which package is the best? In the following it is generating a big matrix but not reducing the quantity of values as expected. Format is just 2 cols. Trying to use in a further analysis, with data sampled not every 0.1 sec but 1 minute.

```
set.seed(1);
time <- rep(seq(0,180,by=0.1));
sl <-runif(1801,-0.1,4.0);
data1 <-  cbind2(time,sl);

#Output needed...
time(min)   sl(cm)


#Examples tried:

time<-data1$V1
SL<-data1$V2
seq1 <- zoo(order.by=((seq(min(time), max(time), by=30))))

mer1 <- merge(zoo(x=data1[1:2],order.by=time), seq1)
#Linear interpolation
dataL <- na.approx(mer1)
```

Comment: Check if you could use `aggregate` function.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data that shows the formats you are looking at and, ideally, desired output?

Comment: @Brian Fisher, thank you I incorporate a very general example, not sure will help, but this is the idea of what I am trying to do. Also, I will try moving average.

Comment: @Amber can you explain what you are looking for/how you come up with the desired results?  In the example you provide, the input is labeled as seconds, so you don't have anything that would interpolate to minute 1 (60 seconds), if we interpret it as fractions of a minute, and the point you want to interpolate is at 1, there's already a data point for that (17.25), but your output says you get 33, which is outside the range of your example data. Do you want to fit a curve or summarize your data?

Comment: @Brian Fisher, what I put is a desired result (I didn't copy all the input). The input is in seconds (sampling every 1 sec), the output in minutes. I want to resample or downsample. Instead of 14,400 samples (every 1 sec), the output should have 240 values instead (every one minute). I can do this in different ways, I was asking which might be the best way (in case that moving average, for example, was a better approach). I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Amber you might want to look at the suggestions for providing a reproducible example, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  There are a lot of ways to resample or downscale your data, any one of which may, or may not be appropriate, depending on the structure of your data, and your goals. One way you could handle it is to summarize by a dummy variable eg minute = round(seconds/60,0) then summarize based on your new minute variable.  You could also fit a model eg. loess(sl~seconds, span = .1) then predict results based on the model at 1 minute intervals.

Comment: For this example you should provide at least 3 minutes worth of data (could be simulated), and what you are trying to achieve with your resampling.   Are you trying to save on memory, or summarizing for reporting, or trying to use in a further analysis?  To answer the which might be the best way, you need to include what your criteria are (fastest, least code, most true to actual measurements, etc)

Comment: @Brian Fisher I am trying to use in a further analysis, with data sampled not every 0.1 sec but 1 minute. I edited the question. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution.  This approach does not use any linear interpolation, but takes the average centered on each minute.

```
library(dplyr) # for group_by and summarize
colnames(data1) <- c("time", "sl")  # makes it easier to call variables by names
data1 <- as.data.frame(data1)  
data1$minute <- round(data1$time/60,0)  #
head(data1)
#  time        sl minute
# 1  0.0 0.9885855      0
# 2  0.1 1.4257080      0
# 3  0.2 2.2486988      0
# 4  0.3 3.6236519      0
# 5  0.4 0.7268959      0
# 6  0.5 3.5833977      0

data_by_minute <- data1 %>%
      group_by(minute) %>%
      summarize(sl_avg = mean(sl))
data_by_minute

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   minute sl_avg
#    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1      0   1.91
# 2      1   1.98
# 3      2   1.87
# 4      3   1.96
```

An alternative approach if you just want to take the actual readings once a minute, rather than computing the average:

```
data1[data1$time%%60==0,]  # only returns the observations on the minute. throws everything else out
#      time sl
# 1       0 0.9885855
# 601    60 3.2384322
# 1201  120 1.4027590
# 1801  180 0.1525986
```

Or if you are looking for an interpolated value you could use:

```
minutes <- time/60  # calculate minutes based on the time variable
mod_leoss <- loess(minutes~sl) # fit a loess model to your data, this is essentially a smoothed version of your sl data based on time
Minute <- c(0,1,2,3)  # minutes for which you want a predicaiton
SL_Preds <- predict(mod_leoss, Minute)  # calculate values from the model

tableA <- cbind(Minute, SL_Preds)
tableA
#      Minute SL_Preds
# [1,]      0 1.665899
# [2,]      1 1.463291
# [3,]      2 1.445809
# [4,]      3 1.498165
```